# How to make a installer which involve .Net Framework (3.5 or later)?

Tags: .net, frameworks, installation, packaging

I want to build a package (installer) which involve .NET framework (3.5 or later). With this installer, installing .NET framework is transparent with user. Please help me!

Comment: ClickOnce installers can install the .NET framework, but it is not 100% transparent, though there may be ways to make it like that.

Comment: "Transparent" as in the user does not know the framework is being installed on their machine, or as in if they need it, it gets installed automatically?

Comment: @Jay: mean automatically

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: please give me a sample (or some guide)

Comment: In VisualStudio, you can choose to make a ClickOnce deployment, and there is a way to set .NET 3.5 as a dependency and that it should be installed if not present. The installer is not "transparent" though, the user will know it's happening and may have to click through an EULA or something... Follow-up with Flavio, it sounds like he's got a better idea than I do of how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will depend on the installer tool you are using. If you are manually checking if .NET 3.5 is already installed (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\Install == 1) and launch the dotNetFx35setup.exe if needed, simply using the the parameter "**/q**" (or "**/quiet**") should prevent it from displaying a user interface during the installation. You can find lots of examples how to do this with Inno Setup.